# How can I use the results of a stored procedure in the column list in a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

How can I have the results of a stored procedure be in the column list of a select statement?  I need to insert new records into a database that has an odd key generation scheme, i.e. one that is result of a stored procedure.

I am trying to do a simple insert-select query in Sql Server 2012, to wit something like this

```
Insert Into OldTable (
StrangelyDerivedKey, FirstName, LastName
)
Select (Exec dbo.GetKey()), FirstName, LastName FROM NewTable
```

Ordinarily I would just use a User Defined Function for the "GetKey()" functionality, but since this is code that does an insert and update Sql Server won't let me do that in a UDF.

How can I get Sql Server to accept the result of a stored procedure as a column?  If I wanted to do a string it would be no problem.  Seemingly this is a syntactic quirk that is solved by another syntactic quirk, but I really can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: Can't you just accept the result of dbo.GetKey() into a variable, then use the variable in your select statement?

Comment: Ah - my mistake - you're selecting a set of rows from "NewTable", and need a new key generated for each row.

Comment: Steve, how many times do you need to do this?  And how many records are in NewTable?  If this is a one-off exercise, perhaps you could copy NewTable to a table variable or temp table, add a column for the new Id and just populate new Ids in a loop?

Comment: It needs to run every day - and the query will need to be modified periodically.

Comment: What does `dbo.GetKey()` do? perhaps we can help you re-write it to produce a set of new keys based on the number of rows in the table

Comment: @SteveFrench You do not do the insert in the UDF, you make a  UDF that provides the key value and call it from the select that provides the table rows

Answer (score 0):

This is something that is UDF based, that may work for you.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetKey()
RETURNS @t TABLE (StrangelyDerivedKey varchar(20))
AS
BEGIN
    -- Do whatever you want here to derive a value, this is just for testing
    INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('fodinpwe8hpi9un')
    RETURN
END

GO

-- INSERT INTO OldTable (StrangelyDerivedKey, FirstName, LastName)
SELECT B.StrangelyDerivedKey, A.FirstName, A.LastName 
FROM NewTable A 
    CROSS APPLY 
    dbo.udf_GetKey() B
```

Change the UDF up to do whatever you need to derive a key. Add parameters to the UDF to make the key based on something you pass it.

Comment: Sadly, the UDF will not allow me do do an insert.

Comment: That's interesting. I tested doing an insert like this without issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can just directly use the function within the SELECT statement

```
INSERT INTO OldTable (StrangelyDerivedKey, 
                      FirstName, 
                      LastName)
SELECT dbo.GetKey(),
       FirstName, 
       LastName 
  FROM NewTable;
```

However, with this select, you will have all the firstname and lastname records from table newtable have the same value for strangelyderivedkey returned by the function. You might want to have some condition in where clause.

Since this is just a sample query, this will do for you.